# How to access media file's URL from within template?

Tags: python, django

This question regards development server.

I have an audio file `audio1.wav` sitting in my `MEDIA_ROOT/audio` folder.
How can I attach such element to an `<audio>` tag in the template?

```
<audio src="?"></audio>
```

Do I need to construct an absolute URL for the file like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/audio/audio1.wav` (given `MEDIA_URL` is set to `/media/`)?

If so, how? Or perhaps there is a better way that will also cover for variable audio file name?

Comment: `{% media 'audio/audio.wav' %}`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Hmm , I get `TemplateSyntaxError at /
Invalid block tag on line 19: 'media'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`. Also I cannot find any mention of such tag in the docs.

Comment: `MEDIA` in Django is treated as _uploaded by users, editable, "dynamic"_ files. Sounds like yours is static. So you could put it into `/static/media/audio` and utilize `static` template tag. _Media_ files are supposed to have appropriate DB records and a model instance with ImageFile/File field which has `.file.url` property which must be used to access these files.

Comment: @IvanStarostin: Thanks, that is helpful! In my app the user will be able to choose a Youtube video that will be subsequently downloaded to media folder and chopped into small audio samples (he can then download the samples as zip). When he chooses another video, all of the old audio files will be deleted and replaced with the new ones. Do you you think that this is a case for using static and a database instead of media, as per your comment?

Comment: They should definitely stored in media, however instead of accessing them directly, I would rather store them in a model, with `ForeignKey` to original video model and `FileField` to the piece. Way easier to manage, if you have multiple users at once.

Comment: No, such files do not seem to be _static_. I assume they are managed manually by your code (not by Django framework features) so the rest of the code around them will be custom too. In this case @Gasanov's answer is probably exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [get_media_prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix) to get media url:

```
{% load static %}
<audio src="{% get_media_prefix %}audio/audio1.wav"></audio>
```